# Removing `<li>` with appended anchor tag leaves style attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps-api-3

I have a Question that has been preventing me to move on for 3 days

I have a List that is appended with Anchor Tags but when I remove it the anchor tag changes to `style:none` and the `<li>` styles remain.

I use it on Google maps when the Marker is out of Map Bounds. I want the whole `<li>` that contains the anchor tag to be removed but the anchor tag is removed not the `<li>`.

Here is my Code.

```
var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
function codeAddress() {
    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        map: map,
        shadowStyle: 0,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        arrowSize: 15,
        maxWidth: 300,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        arrowPosition: 50,
        arrowStyle: 0
    });
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList', function Geocode(addresses) {
        $.each(addresses, function () {
            var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
            var Name = this["Name"];
            var Gender = this["Gender"];
            var Bdate = this["Birthdate"];
            var ID = this["Worker_ID"];
            var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
            var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
            var LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                position: LatLang,
                title: currVal
            })

            var link = $('<a href="#">' + currVal + '</a>')
                 .data('location', LatLang);
            $('#places').append($('<li id=\'List\' class=\'List\'>').append(link));
            link.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(addresses[0], "click");
                infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Worker/WorkerDetails?workerId=' + ID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                    $('#places').find('li a').css('display', function () {
                        return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                  ? ''
                  : 'none';
                    });
                });



            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                    infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Worker/WorkerDetails?workerId=' + ID + '">View Profile</a></center>');
                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, currVal));
            addresses.push(marker);

        })
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');
    })
}
```

when it Loaded , Look at the 2nd Image, notice that the style still remains

[image: When it Loaded]

[image]

Styles

```
<style>
    .List
    {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .List:nth-child(odd)
    {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: We need the surrounding code for this.  There is no context for your script here so this could either be executing inside of a `for()` loop, on it's own during a page load, attached to an event handler (like a `click`) or something else.  Please post the rest of your Javascript and CSS.

Comment: @Deryck Added the rest of the javascript

Comment: @Deryck updated the CSS and the new JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Old:**

```
$('#places li').css('display', function () {
    return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location'))) ? '' : 'none';
});
```

**New:**

```
$('#places > li').each(function() {
    var inside = (map.getBounds().contains($(this).find('a').data('location'))) ? '' : 'none';
    $(this).css('display', inside);
});
```

Try this out

Comment: sir i just want to clarify that i've changed the `$('#places li').css('display',function(){ return(map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))?'' : 'none';});` to `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                        $('#places').find('li a').css('display', function () {
                            return (map.getBounds().contains($(this).data('location')))
                      ? ''
                      : 'none';
                        });
                    });`

Comment: If you do that you'll only have your `<a>` changed.  You need to select the `li`, not `li a`.  If somehow that works for you, wonderful.  But if not, try my fix.

Comment: yeah.. thats what happened it only changes my `<a>` and not including `<li>`

Comment: can you edit the answer that is appropriate to the edited code?

Comment: So when you use the code that you just typed above in the first comment to this answer, it changes `<a>` and not `<li>`?

Comment: Yeah. . Its adding `style:none` only on `<a>` but remains the `<li>`

Comment: Did you replace that code inside the event handler you made with the code I posted instead?

Comment: Thanks sir . . You helped me alot :) saved me from being doomed . . Tried the code you provide and it works :)

Comment: sir another question. . is there a solution because when i inspect element . . i can see all the other marker that is not on bounds with `display:none` , how can i remove those and shows only the one who is present on maps?? thanks

Comment: Just replace `$(this).css('display', inside);` with `$(this).remove();`.  Just be aware this will actually delete the instance from the DOM and to get it back you'll have to re-query the map by executing `codeAddress()` manually (or set it to do so upon zoom in/out, etc).  I would recommend caching the results from the first run into either a cookie or localStorage as an object or array to reference later.  Good luck :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46405/discussion-between-ren-tao-and-deryck)